# Stored procedure creation error in SQL Server 2022

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I attached a database to SQL Server 2022 version and added a new table `URLabelHeader`. While adding a new stored procedure I am getting the following error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spSaveURLprocess]  
    (@tblURLlabelHeader [dbo].tblURLabelHeader READONLY)
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;.....
```

Error:

> Msg 2715, Level 16, State 3, Procedure spSaveURLprocess, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 6]
> Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type dbo.tblURLlabelHeader.
> Parameter or variable '@tblURLlabelHeader' has an invalid data type.
>
> The parameter @tblURLlabelHeader cannot be declared READONLY since it is not a table-valued parameter.

Can anyone please help me?

I try to add a new stored procedure in SQL Server 2022.

Comment: What exactly does this question have to do with C#? If there is some connection then your question is inadequate because it doesn't describe it in any way. If there is no connection then please remove the irrelevant tag. Tags exist for a reason and you waste people's time if you add irrelevant ones. You also say that this is in SQL Server and yet there's no tags that indicate that. Use the appropriate tags and you'll get the right eyes on your question to get an answer and you won't annoy other people in the process.

Comment: Well - have you **defined** that user-defined data type `[dbo].tblURLabelHeader` in your database, **before** trying to create this stored procedure?

Comment: Looks like you seem to think that a table and a table type are the same: they are not. One uses `CREATE TABLE` the other uses `CREATE TYPE ... AS TABLE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after @tblURLlabelHeader you must define it's type. like  @tblURLlabelHeader Varchar(8000).

There is no such value type tblURLabelHeader in [SQL server 2022](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-user-defined-data-type-alias?view=sql-server-ver16)

So that is a user defined data type. and you must create that user-defined data type, before creating your new SP.

You can find definition of that data type in : Programmability>Types>User-Defined Table types. (First create that data Type)